# Changing the Method Name in Description

Tags: java, junit4

I know that using:

```
Description.createSuiteDescription(label);
```

where Description is a:

```
org.junit.runner.Description
```

one can change the Display name of a method ( getDisplayName() ).

Is it possible to change the Method Name ( getMethodName() ) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
createTestDescription(java.lang.Class<?> clazz, java.lang.String name)
```

Create a Description of a single test named name in the class clazz.

Look here for the api about descriptions and custom junit stuff:
http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/runner/Runner.html